# Swift 4 pasteboard to Finder

Tags: swift, swift4

What Pasteboard types are accepted by Finder on MacOS 10.12?
The following code let's me drag to other applications (like Terminal and Sublime), but Finder does not accept it. Is it a problem of PasteboardType, or am I missing something else?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mediaInUseTableView.setDraggingSourceOperationMask(NSDragOperation.every, forLocal: false)
}
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, writeRowsWith rowIndexes: IndexSet, to pboard: NSPasteboard) -> Bool {
    var urls = [NSURL]()
    var types = [NSPasteboard.PasteboardType]()
//        types.append(NSPasteboard.PasteboardType(kUTTypeURL as String))
//        types.append(NSPasteboard.PasteboardType("NSURLPboardType"))
    types.append(NSPasteboard.PasteboardType("NSFilenamesPboardType"))
//        types.append(NSPasteboard.PasteboardType.string)
    for row in rowIndexes{
        urls.append(self.mediaInUses[row].url.absoluteURL as NSURL)
//            types.append(NSPasteboard.PasteboardType.fileNameType(forPathExtension: self.mediaInUses[row].url.pathExtension))
    }
    pboard.declareTypes(types, owner: nil)
    pboard.writeObjects(urls)
    return true
}
```

A couple of the more promesing types seem unavailable for my environment:

```
NSFilenamesPboardType
'NSFilenamesPboardType' is unavailable in Swift: use 'PasteboardType.fileURL'
NSPasteboard.PasteboardType.fileURL
'fileURL' is only available on OS X 10.13 or newer
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I spent hours analyzing Finder's own drag data dropped to my application and trying countless variations of objects in .declareTypes, .setPropertyList and .setData. I had it work once (!), then break again on the same code.
I also switched to Swift 3.2 in desperation. Today, I realized that **.writeObjects is supposed to automate all the above based on its input**, and tested a minimal implementation, which worked fine with other applications. When this did not work in Finder, I got convinced the problem had to lie somewhere else.

Hypothesis: Finder was blacklisting my application due to invalid attempts.

Solution: **Restarted the computer**, and suddenly Finder was accepting the drag!

I had a couple of restarts yesterday as well, but I probably had a bad implementation at that point.

Minimal implementation **(Swift 3/4)**:

```
// Enable drag to other applications:
tableView.setDraggingSourceOperationMask(NSDragOperation.every, forLocal: false)
// Serve data for dragged table rows:
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, writeRowsWith rowIndexes: IndexSet, to pboard: NSPasteboard) -> Bool {
    // Prepeare data:
    var arrayOfNSURLs = [NSURL]()
    for rowIndex in rowIndexes{
        arrayOfNSURLs.append(self.mediaFiles[rowIndex].url.absoluteURL as NSURL)
    }
    // Let API write objects automatically:
    pboard.writeObjects(arrayOfNSURLs)
    return true
}
```

Here is my full implementation **(Swift 3/4)**:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Enable global drag (to other applications)
    mediaFilesTableView.setDraggingSourceOperationMask(NSDragOperation.every, forLocal: false)
    sourceClipsTableView.setDraggingSourceOperationMask(NSDragOperation.every, forLocal: false)
}
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, writeRowsWith rowIndexes: IndexSet, to pboard: NSPasteboard) -> Bool {
    if tableView == self.mediaFilesTableView {
        var arrayOfNSURLs = [NSURL]()
        for row in rowIndexes{
            arrayOfNSURLs.append(self.mediaFiles[row].url.absoluteURL as NSURL)
        }
        pboard.writeObjects(arrayOfNSURLs)
        return true
    }
    if tableView == self.sourceClipsTableView {
        var names = [NSString]()
        var info = ""
        for row in rowIndexes{
            info = "\(self.sourceClips[row].mediaFiles.count)"
            if info == "0"{
                info = "MISSING"
            }
            names.append(self.sourceClips[row].name.padding(toLength: 30, withPad: " ", startingAt: 0) + info as NSString)
        }
        pboard.writeObjects(names)
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

EDIT: Switched back to Swift 4, and these lines seem to be the same as in Swift 3.